# Python 3 and files are missing in Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I open my Jupyter notebook, the files are missing, and I cannot create a python 3 file. And when I click the text file, this message Appears "'_xsrf' argument missing from POST"

Answer (score 0):

There are a few potential causes for this problem.

One possibility is that the Jupyter notebook server is not running.

Another possibility is that the Jupyter notebook server is not configured to use Python

Finally, it is also possible that the Jupyter notebook server is not able to find the Python 3 interpreter.